# Homomorphic image of $S_{8}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

(1). Can $S_{8}$ be a homomorphic image of $S_{12}.$

(2). can $S_{8}$ be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{12}$

For 2 if we use the result that $S_{m}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{n}$ iff $m \leq n$ then 2 is true. But what about 1.

Answer (score 6):

You have the right idea for the second part.  If you don't already know it, think about what the embedding $\Psi: S_m \hookrightarrow S_n$ when $m \leq n$ actually is; i.e. given an element $\pi \in S_m$, what element of $S_n$ is $\Psi(\pi)$?  The map is quite "natural", so no need to overthink this.

---

For the first part, suppose we have a surjective homomorphism $\phi: S_{12} \rightarrow S_8$.  Applying the [first isomorphism theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstGroupIsomorphismTheorem.html), we have $S_{12}/\ker(\phi) \cong S_8$.  The existence of this quotient group depends on the fact$^\dagger$ that [the kernel of a group homomorphism $G \rightarrow G'$ is *always* a normal subgroup of $G$](http://planetmath.org/thekernelofagrouphomomorphismisanormalsubgroup).

What would $|\ker(\phi)|$ need to be for the above isomorphism to hold?  What are the possibilities for $\ker(\phi)$, i.e., the normal subgroups of $S_n$?

In greater generality, you can use this line of argument to classify *every possible* group homomorphism out of all of the symmetric groups.  Be careful with $S_4$ though as it has a normal subgroup (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$) that none of the other symmetric groups have.

---

$^\dagger$As a side-note, the converse of this is also true: if $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, then there exists a homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$ with $\ker(\phi) = N$, namely the [natural projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalProjection.html) $G \rightarrow G/N$ defined such that $g \mapsto gN$.

Comment: order of kernel should divide the order of $S_{12}$

Comment: Indeed @1256, and in particular we'll need to have $|S_{12}| = |S_8| \cdot |\ker(\phi)|$.

Comment: I think,in this case that order of kernel which divides the order of $S_{12}$  are not normal in $S_{8}$

Comment: Yes, there won't be a normal subgroup of $S_{12}$ with the order needed.  What *are* the normal subgroups of $S_n$, particularly when $n \geq 5$?

Comment: For less or equal $m,$  $i$ goes $f(i)$ and for others i.e for $m $ grater than n , $i$ goes to $i$

Comment: eithe $A_{n}$ or $S_{n}$ are the normal subgroup.